# Chaging innerHTML of DIV changes table properties

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have to show dynamically checkboxes in a HTML page and get their value from database.

The trick I used is to create the whole table HTML in java and then using AJAX I do this

```
var div = document.getElementByID("div").innerHTML = htmlCode;
```

but issue is

in htmlCode variable, the html is like

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
       <td width="50%">......
```

but when I check div.innerHTML it shows like

```
<TABLE width="100%">
<TBODY>
    <TR>
        <TD width="50%">
            <?xml:namespace prefix = ....
```

Why they become uppercase and why is xml:namaesapce prefix added ?

This causes issue as table is not properly displayed.

Is there any other better way to do this without using innerHTML ?

The code for generation of table is

```
String html = "<table width=\"100%\">";

for (Iterator it = lookupList.iterator (); it.hasNext ();)
    {
        HashTree lookupElement = (HashTree) it.next ();
        String code = lookupElement.getChildTagValue ("CODE");
        String text = lookupElement.getChildTagValue ("TEXT");

        String labelText = "";

            if(indexLookupElement == 0)
                labelText = "First Checkbox label";

            html = html + "<tr><td width=\"50%\" >" +
             +
                    "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"item" + code + "\"  />" +
                    "<html:label " +    
                        "id=\"_Description\"" + 
                        "name=\"_Description\"" + 
                        ">" + text +
                    "</html:label>" +                       


            "<td width=\"50%\"  >" + 
            "</td></tr>";

            indexLookupElement += 1;
    }

html = html + "</table>";
```

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: Dont take it as an answer but `document.getElementByID` is wrong..it should be  `document.getElementById` (id=lowercase) and `div.innerHTML` is probably `undefined` .. you should provide more code https://jsfiddle.net/uo2gjvxL/12/

Comment: Please provide the part of code where you generate html

Comment: I simply do like this   in main page....create a div.....then create table<table width=\"100%\"> in java string and then inside that table dynamically add <tr> then <td> and then checkbox code. I repeat the  <tr> and checkboxes as many times as there are checkboxes in database, which is dynamic and can change

Comment: I have updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a best practice to create the HTML code server-side. If you are sure you'll have the table in your document it's better to make it part of the structure of the document and feed only the variables from your Java code. Even if the table is conditional you may consider hide/unhide it with a variable. I believe this approach will solve your problem if the HTML code of your webpage is correct.

Update

Test it like this:

```
html = html + "<tr><td width=\"50%\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"item" + code + "\" /><label id=\"_Description\" name=\"_Description\">" + text + "</label></td><td width=\"50%\"></td></tr>";
```

In your code you have missing TD closing tag and I made some changes. See if this will fix your problem.

Comment: Issue is I get the names / labels of check boxes dynamically in database. It can change anytime by user. I have to pick the database labels / names of check boxes then show them. so, their number isn't fixed. e.g. Book name, book author.....etc user can delete  book author from a table and then we should not create that book author check box